# How Do I Prevent this Code from Randomly Being Called

Tags: vba, excel

I'm developing a script in VBA for excel and currently I'm working on deleting every sheet but "Jan2016" and then copying "Jan2016" and renaming it several times.  Unfortunately, when I run my code, my DeleteAllButJanuary() function is randomly called deleting every sheet but January again and causing it to start over and eventually fail.  Here's my code:

```
Sub GenerateData()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim Jan As Integer
    Dim Months() As String
    Months = Split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec", ",")

    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
    ' workbook.
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    Call DeleteAllButJanuary

    For I = 2 To WS_Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan2016").Copy _
        After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan2016")
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name = Months(I) + "2016"
    Next I
End Sub

'Delete all sheets except the January Sheet
Sub DeleteAllButJanuary()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ThisSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ThisSheet.Name <> "Jan2016" Then
            ThisSheet.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: try putting Application.EnableEvents = False at the start and Application.EnableEvents = True at the end of GenerateData().  Does that help?  My guess is you have some kind of worksheet activate event that's causing the sub to be called multiple times

Comment: That would be my 1st thought, check the code behind the worksheets, see if any trigger deleteallbutjanuary, of CTRL+F for it in your code.

Comment: Use F8 to step into the macro from the vba editor, then keep on clicking F8 for each step. You should find the issue quickly.

Comment: You should probably set `Application.DisplayAlerts` back to `True` at some point in the code.

Comment: I would use the `Application.Caller` object at the beginning to track where it comes from... simply set a variable to it and then pause the code having "watches" to track down the path to the source of the call...

Comment: Comment out the call to `DeleteAllButJanuary` from within `GenerateData`, then run  `DeleteAllButJanuary` manually followed by `GenerateData`.  Does that work?  FYI `Months(2)` is Mar not Feb, since the array is zero-based.

Comment: @sous2817 that's a very good idea thanks for the help

*| Nathan_Sav I don't think any code behind the worksheets is doing anything since this is the first macro in the sheet

*| nutsch Wow this was incredibly helpful to my problems.  Thanks for the tip!

*| DirkReichel I'll try to do that now

*| TimWilliams Thanks so much, the difference between worksheet and array indexing was confusing me

I somehow fixed the problem by changing the For loop to be constants (numbers in a month).  I wish I had an answer as the why the original didn't work but I don't. (Sorry for the formatting)

Comment: You are always inserting after sheet 'Jan2016' which since you have deleted all other sheets means you will always be copying into worksheet(2). Thus ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name will access the wrong sheets.

Changing it to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Name should allow you to rename each sheet correctly (although the book will be in reverse order)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly edited code with some further error checking added

```
Sub GenerateData()
    If Not WorkSheetExists("Jan2016") Then Exit Sub

    Dim WS_Count As Integer, i As Integer, Jan As Integer
    Dim Months() As String
    Months = Split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec", ",")

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For Each ThisSheet In .Worksheets
            If ThisSheet.Name <> "Jan2016" Then ThisSheet.Delete
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        For i = WS_Count To 2 Step -1
            .Worksheets("Jan2016").Copy After:=.Worksheets("Jan2016")
            .Worksheets(2).Name = Months(i - 1) + "2016"
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function WorkSheetExists(ByVal strName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   WorkSheetExists = Not ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Another issue I've just considered is when you are trying to attempt this macro on workbooks which contain more than 12 worksheets; the array 'Months' will throw an error as you will go out of range when attempting to access members that don't exist. You'll need to add some error handling code for that if it is possible to occur

Answer (score 0):

Hope I've got this right.
You want to delete all worksheets, except January. Then you want to use this is a template to repopulate the rest of the months? Is that correct?...

If so, suggest that you delete in reverse order...

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateData()

    Dim I As Integer
    Dim Months() As String
    Months = Split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec", ",")

    Call DeleteAllButJanuary

    For I = UBound(Months) To LBound(Months) + 1 Step -1

        Call Worksheets("Jan2016").Copy(After:=Worksheets("Jan2016"))
        Worksheets(2).Name = Months(I) + "2016"

    Next I

End Sub

Public Sub DeleteAllButJanuary()

On Error Resume Next

Dim I As Integer
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Call Sheets("Jan2016").Move(Sheets(1))
For I = Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1
    Sheets(I).Delete
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```